# how to subtract one day from second row in r?

Tags: r

I need to update the Date2 column by calculating the next record_date of the ID.
(i.e) The Date2 column should be (record_date-1) of next record_date of ID

My dataset is like:

```
ID  Date1
123 05-06-2012
123 06-08-2012
123 09-09-2013
234 05-04-2014
234 06-09-2014
```

I need cumulative type date format (i.e) Expected results

```
ID  Date1       Date2
123 05-06-2012  05-08-2012
123 06-08-2012  08-09-2013
123 09-09-2013  NA
234 05-04-2014  05-09-2014
234 06-09-2014  NA
```

Comment: What did you try? Where did it fail? What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the `Date1` to date class and subtract 1 date from the next date for each `ID`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date1 = lubridate::dmy(Date1)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Date2 = lead(Date1) - 1)

#    ID Date1      Date2     
#  <int> <date>     <date>    
#1   123 2012-06-05 2012-08-05
#2   123 2012-08-06 2013-09-08
#3   123 2013-09-09 NA        
#4   234 2014-04-05 2014-09-05
#5   234 2014-09-06 NA
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 234L, 234L), 
Date1 = c("05-06-2012", "06-08-2012", "09-09-2013", "05-04-2014", "06-09-2014")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```